# PostgreSQL : Can I retrieve log_min_duration_statement as an integer?

Tags: postgresql, settings

My problem is the following :

I update the setting "log_min_duration_statement" described as an integer in postgreSQL documentation (version 9.5 is used). I use the following query to update it : "**SET log_min_duration_statement to [numberOfMilliseconds]**"

When I try to fetch the updated value I get a duration **string** formatted either in milliseconds (like **"250ms"**) or in seconds (like **"10s"**). I use **"SHOW log_min_duration_statement"** to retrieve the value. I would like to retrieve that value **as an integer representing milliseconds** instead of having it formatted as text with varying units.

Does anyone know about a way to do that ?

Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: Thank you, this works fine and is what I was hoping for. If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SHOW log_min_duration_statement` returns the text value in the [interval type input compatible form](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT).

So it can be converted to the `interval` type but it is impossible using `SHOW` command. So lets use `current_setting` function instead:

```
select current_setting('log_min_duration_statement')::interval;
```

Then to convert interval into milliseconds:

```
select extract(epoch from current_setting('log_min_duration_statement')::interval) * 1000;
```